# How to make a properly request to a "multipart/form-data" form using Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

So i have the following snippet that create a **multi-part/form**:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
from random import random
from sys import maxsize


def gen_boundary():
    alpha_numeric_encoding_map = \
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789AB'

    boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary'

    for i in range(4):
        boundary += alpha_numeric_encoding_map[int(random() * (maxsize + 1)) >> 24 & 0x3F]
        boundary += alpha_numeric_encoding_map[int(random() * (maxsize + 1)) >> 16 & 0x3F]
        boundary += alpha_numeric_encoding_map[int(random() * (maxsize + 1)) >> 8 & 0x3F]
        boundary += alpha_numeric_encoding_map[int(random() * (maxsize + 1)) & 0x3F]

    return boundary


payload = dict(new='order', type='misc')

me = MultipartEncoder(fields=payload, boundary=gen_boundary())
me_body = me.to_string()

headers = {'Content-Type': me.content_type, 'Content-Length': me.len}
```

With this i call **Request**:

```
yield Request(url='http://example.com/test',body=me_body, headers=headers, callback=self.test)
```

My problem is that always the request return **500 Internal Server Error**, what could i do make this request work? I missing something?

I even try change lib:

```
from urllib3 import encode_multipart_formdata
body, headers = encode_multipart_formdata(fields=payload, boundary=self.gen_boundary())
```

The result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging a little bit a found that i missed a request before i submit the form! After i make the request the form as submitted successfully.

Comment: Will you please explain the solution? I'm facing the same issue.